# How to find i4jlauncher.config?

Tags: java, install4j

I got the following error showing that it can not find i4jlauncher.config. How can I let it find the file? Is there an option or environment variable that I should specify?

```
$ pwd
/Applications/thinkorswim/thinkorswim.app
$ java -cp '/Applications/thinkorswim/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar:/Applications/thinkorswim/launcher-first.jar:/Applications/thinkorswim/launcher.jar'  com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher
error2: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/Contents/Resources/i4jlauncher.config (No such file or directory)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher.readProperties(MacLauncher.java:64)
com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher.main(MacLauncher.java:29)

$ ls Contents/Resources/i4jlauncher.config
Contents/Resources/i4jlauncher.config
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the working directory to `/Applications/thinkorswim/.install4j` or pass `-Dinstall4j.runtimeDir=<path to .install4j directory` on the command line.